# Not a Java source folder when creating New JPA Entity in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating an EJB Project, and then would like to make new JPA Entity, but when I typed the Class Name and the Package Name, I got the error: `Not a Java source folder` and below are the error and my project facets settings. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

[image]

[image: Project Facets Setting]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the ejbModule folder in Eclipse's explorer window, Click Build Path >> Use as Source Folder.

If you do this prior to what you have been attempting to do, it might work.